# PythonでEXCELの列を別へのエクセルへ貼り付けたい[より簡単な方法]

Tags: python, python3

Python3 と openpyxl のライブラリを使って、Excelの列をコピーして別のエクセルへ貼り付けています。
下記の方法で行うと元のエクセルのデータが列が増えた分
新規のエクセルへ貼り付けます。
openpyxl以外により良い簡単方法ないでしょうか。
PANDASでも可能でしょうか。

①Excelデータ

| No | 駅 | 駅2 | フラグ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 東京 | 品川 | 処理済み |
| 2 | 原宿 | 原宿 | 処理済み |
| 3 | 日暮里 | 秋葉原 |  |
| 4 | 東京 | 原宿 |  |
| 5 | 池袋 | @@@ |  |

②Excelデータ

| No | 駅 | 駅2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 東京 | 品川 |
| 2 | 原宿 | 原宿 |
| 3 |  | 秋葉原 |
| 4 |  | 原宿 |
| 5 | 池袋 | @@@ |

（実現内容）
＞①のEXCELフラグの列をコピーして②のEXCELへ貼り付ける

| No | 駅 | 駅2 | フラグ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 東京 | 品川 | 処理済み |
| 2 | 原宿 | 原宿 | 処理済み |
| 3 |  | 秋葉原 |  |
| 4 |  | 原宿 |  |
| 5 | 池袋 | @@@ |  |

コード

```
# #EXCELflag別へのエクセルへ貼り付ける
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
import openpyxl


file_time= dt.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

filename_xlsx="TEST1.xlsx"
file_completion = "TEST2.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename_xlsx)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
i = 1
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    #[if cell.col_idx == 1:] で、コピー元の①ExcelデータD列を指定しています。
    for cell in row:
        if cell.col_idx == 1:
            ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = cell.value
            i = i + 1
wb.save(file_completion)
#別名で保存
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: > 下記のコードだと①のEXCELのNO、駅、駅２、フラグのカラムが全てコピーされます。 ⇒　同じシートのセルを上書き処理しているだけではないですか？
>フラグだけをコピして②EXCELへ貼り付けたいですが、どのようにすればい良いでしょうか。 ⇒　コピー先のエクセルを開いていないように見えます。ご確認ください。

Comment: @merino さん回答ありがとうございます。
コピー先のエクセルを開いても同じように全てコピーされます。
フラグだけをコピして②EXCELへ貼り付けたいです。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。下記の方法でできました。`if cell.col_idx == 1:　ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = cell.value`より簡単な方法あれば教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

行数の少なさ、処理の理解しやすさ、といった面ではpandasを使って以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('TEST1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('TEST2.xlsx')

df2['フラグ'] = df1['フラグ']

df2.to_excel('TEST2.xlsx', index=False)
```

ただし、pandasの`.to_excel()`を使うとヘッダーの行が以下のように太字かつ罫線付きに変わります。

[image: pandas_TEST2]

---

こちらの記事を参考に`df2.to_excel()`を以下のように置き換えて極力見た目を合わせることは可能ですが、せっかくデータの処理は簡単に出来るのに書き込み処理がこれでは本末転倒でしょうね。
[pandasでExcel書込み時に幅/高さ,中央揃え,折り返しをStyleFrameで変更する](https://yuki.world/pandas-dataframe-excel-styling/)
[styleframe](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler, utils
style = Styler(font='游ゴシック', font_size=11, bold=False, border_type=None, fill_pattern_type=None, horizontal_alignment=utils.horizontal_alignments.left)
styleNum = Styler(font='游ゴシック', font_size=11, bold=False, border_type=None, fill_pattern_type=None, horizontal_alignment=utils.horizontal_alignments.right)

with StyleFrame.ExcelWriter('TEST2.xlsx') as writer:
    sf = StyleFrame(df2, styler_obj=style)
    sf.apply_headers_style(styler_obj=style)
    sf.apply_column_style(cols_to_style='No', styler_obj=styleNum, style_header=True)
    sf.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

[image: StyleFrame_TEST2]

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。pandasでもできますね。理解しやすいです。早速使ってみます。